# How to sum based on specific length text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have one excel file which I design it below. I have main accounts and sub accounts. Now I want to sum only main accounts which lenth = 2.

I wrote this formula:

```
=sumproduct((len(account range)=2)*sum range)
```

But it does not work properly.

```
Account #      Dr
--------------------
60             85$
60.01          50$
60.02          35$
50            120$         
50.01         100$      
50.02          20$
```

Answer (score 2):

You have almost done it. Try like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(A1:A6)=2),B1:B6)
```

The `--` takes the boolean value of `LEN(A1:A6)=2` per each cell and makes it a number.